# open a popup page with javascript which has 3 variable( page id, url , t) and close this page after time(t)

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow, window.open

I want to write a javascript function which get some variables and then open popup window. then another function close this window after t second.
for example
    
    `openwindow = function(id,url,time){
    id=window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
    closewindow = function(id){
    id.open();
    }`
    
and want it work like this:
    
    `var id1;
    var url="http://google.com";
    var time=60;
    openwindow(id1,url,time);`

help me please...

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout function executes a function after waiting for the specified number of milliseconds.This is what you can do:

```js
var openPopUp = function(popUpId, url, time) {
  popUpId = window.open(url,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
  setTimeout(function() {
    popUpId.close();
  }, time);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent Page</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Parent Page</h1>
 <h2><button onClick="openPopUp('id1', 'https://google.com', 3000);">Click</button></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you verify your answer please ? I got this error when I click on the button "InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object"

Comment: its working on my system. InvalidAccessError may appear due to some cross origin requests.